# FAB неправильной формы

Tags: android, android-studio

При добавлении fab в layout она становится не круглой, а квадратной. В чем проблема? Спасибо заранее за помощь.

build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hfad.constraintliving"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hfad.constraintliving">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.hfad.constraintliving.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewHeader"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/header"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,9:16"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewPoster"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/poster"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageViewHeader"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,2:3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageViewHeader" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewMovieHeading"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/title_of_movie"

        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewPoster"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageViewHeader" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_bookmark"
        android:tint="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageViewHeader" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="16dp" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.95555556" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/additional_info"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/film_info"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewPoster"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewMovieHeading"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="imageViewPoster,additional_info"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="128dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/rent_button"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/rent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/buy_button"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/barrier"
        tools:targetApi="m" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buy_button"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/buy"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/rent_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/barrier"
        tools:targetApi="m" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/checkbox_on_background"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rent_button" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: screen]

Comment: "@android:drawable/checkbox_on_background" скорей всего содержат ещё и states которые меняют элемент, используйте свое изображение, которое будет рисовать поверх fab

Comment: вы сами указали кнопке  изображение `checkbox_on_background`, а теперь спрашиваете, почему она выглядит, как чекбокс

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте убрать

`android:src="@android:drawable/checkbox_on_background"`

в

`android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton`